# AWS CLI S3 sync exclude folder from an array

Tags: amazon-web-services, synchronization, command-line-interface

I have the following PowerShell code for transferring files from a folder and exclude certain folders. I pass the excluded folder to an array but that doesn't work.

```
$websitebucket="test"

  
function websitesync($sourcesite,$destinationsite,$exclude){

 $complist=$exclude
foreach($comp in $complist){
       
   $comparray += " --exclude="   + """$comp"""   
   
}
$comparray

aws s3 sync $sourcesite s3://$websitebucket/$destinationsite $comparray   

}

websitesync -sourcesite "D:\tmp\s3test" -destinationsite "bucket" -exclude '/log/*' ,'csv/*','Log/*'
```

Comment: What is the contents of the final command that it is trying to run (after variables have been substituted)? What do you mean by "that doesn't work"? I wonder whether it needs to start with a `--include *` before excluding parts? See: [Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Comment: I am getting the following value in  $comparray
   --exclude="/log/*" --exclude="csv/*" --exclude="Log/*" but the final error is  Unknown options:  --exclude=/log/* --exclude=csv/* --exclude=Log/*

Comment: If you run this command, does it complain about Access Denied, or Unknown Options? `aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/a/ s3://my-bucket/b/ --exclude="/log/*" --exclude="csv/*" --exclude="Log/*"`

Comment: If I run the following command without the array value  its working 
aws s3 sync $sourcesite s3://$websitebucket/$destinationsite --exclude="/log/*" --exclude="csv/*" --exclude="Log/*"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045423/aws-cli-s3-sync-how-to-exclude-multiple-files
Above working from a Linux shell